# RestSharp deserialize list with a DateTime element as a child

Tags: c#, rest, serialization, xml-serialization, restsharp

I have problem to deserialize following xml with RestSharp:

```
<dates>
<date>2013-04-30</date>
<date>2013-04-16</date>
<date>2013-04-05</date>
<date>2013-04-20</date>
<date>2013-04-06</date>
<date>2013-04-13</date>
<date>2013-04-04</date>
</dates>
```

Obviously i need to deserialize that to something like a List of DateTime objects. So I´ve tried something like

```
public class Dates : List<DateTime>
{
}
```

but this is not possible because the DateTime class name does not match the elements "date" name. Of course I´ve set the date format as follows:

```
request.XmlSerializer.DateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
```

So my next step was

```
public class Dates
{
  [SerializeAs(Name="date")]
  List<DateTime> dates;
}
```

But this is not working either, collection is still returning empty. I understand mixing dateTime parsing and lists with single element as a child is...inconvenient. Is this even possible to parse this kind of xml with default RestSharp XmlParser?

Answer (score 0):

You are making your own list class? It seems like you have misunderstood something about how to make XML serializable objects.

Try this instead:

```
public class MyXmlObject
{
    [XmlArray(ElementName = "dates")]
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "date")]
    List<DateTime> Dates;
}
```